# Fatal Python Error with SQLAlchemy connect_engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to use Pandas to pull data from a remote DB2 database on an M1 Mac. My script works on a Windows 10 system, but I get a fatal error when I run from my Mac. I've never experienced fatal errors before so I'm not sure how to proceed with troubleshooting. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import os

dsn_database = "mydb"
dsn_hostname = "prod.site.com"
dsn_port = "50001"
dsn_uid = "..."
dsn_pwd = "..."
ssl_trust_store_location = "ROOT.cer"
ssl_trust_password = "..."
credentials = {"host":dsn_hostname,"port":dsn_port,"db":dsn_database,"user":dsn_uid,"pw":dsn_pwd}

mydb_eng = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4};SECURITY=ssl;SSLServerCertificate={5};".format(credentials['user'],credentials['pw'],credentials['host'],str(credentials['port']),credentials['db'],ssl_trust_store_location))

mydb_conn = mydb_eng.connect()

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 100;', mydb_conn)
```

When I run within a virtual environment in Spyder, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Main thread:
Current thread 0x00000002034682c0 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py", line 629 in connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598 in connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578 in connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 680 in __connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386 in __init__
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 271 in _create_connection
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143 in _do_get
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 491 in checkout
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 888 in _checkout
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 325 in connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361 in _wrap_pool_connect
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394 in raw_connection
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96 in __init__
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315 in connect
  File "/Users/lwd/Documents/Projects/mydb_Test/sqlalchemy_test.py", line 18 in <module>
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 469 in exec_code
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 611 in _exec_file
  File "/Users/lwd/opt/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 524 in runfile
  File "/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/ipykernel_14510/3309860273.py", line 1 in <cell line: 1>

Restarting kernel...
```

Line 18 of sqlalchemy_test.py is `mydb_conn = mydb_eng.connect()`. I don't know what to do with this info. So far I've tried:

1. Running the code directly within Terminal.
2. Running the code within Jupyter.
3. Updating all of my packages.
4. Using bad username or password to see if I could prompt a different error message.

No progress yet, I get the same outcome regardless. Can anyone help decipher what Python is trying to tell me?

Comment: What about trying a query using just SQLAlchemy (no pandas)? If that results in the same error, what about trying in Linux?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `;` at the end of the line, right after `SSLServerCertificate={5}`?

Comment: Naming your file `sqlalchemy.py` is probably  bad idea - it may conflict with the sqlalchemy package.

Comment: @tehCheat the error occurs with the create_engine command, so my script isn't getting to the point of issuing the query.

Comment: @jgmh nice find I've updated row 18 to include the closing `;`. Unfortunately no change in outcome.

Comment: @snakecharmerb good point thank you. I've updated the filename to `sqlalchemy_test.py`.

Comment: @Lenwood , have you done any eliminations to narrow down the problem? Edit your question to specify exact versions of everything.  Does a plain ibm_db connect work (i.e. temporarily eliminate sqlalchemy/pandas).  If not, does the clidriver work to allow a command-line connect (db2cli -validate - connect - dsn X -user Y -passwd X  , after configuring your dbsdsdriver.cfg according to Db2-LUW documentation website) .

Comment: Your comment was instructive @mao. I did create a script which only uses ibm_db and the results did not change so it seems my issue has nothing to do with sqlalchemy. I've since begun reading through the [ibm_db docs](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb#pre-requisites) and realized that the setup is different for M1 Macs. My issue isn't solved yet but I'm making progress.

Comment: @Lenwood next step is to temporarily eliminate python, by using the clidriver `db2cli ` validation to perform the connect. If clidriver cannot connect, then nothing built on top of it can work.   There are known issues (and workarounds) for python ibm_db module when used in x64 emulation on M1, see the github python ibm_db page.